# Add an entry to a list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm having trouble to add a dictionary in a list of dictionary. Here is my problem description:

```
>> my_list = [{}]*4
>> my_list
[{}, {}, {}, {}]
>> my_list[0]
{}
>> key=(0,0,0,0)
>> my_list[0][key]=[]
>> my_list[0]     
{(0, 0, 0, 0): []}
```

So far so good, but if I print my_list, this is not what I expected:

```
>> my_list
[{(0, 0, 0, 0): []}, {(0, 0, 0, 0): []}, {(0, 0, 0, 0): []}, {(0, 0, 0, 0): []}]
```

What I expected is:
`[{(0, 0, 0, 0): []}, {}, {}, {}]`

What is going on? I only add one entry into the first element of my_list. I don't expect my_list[1:3] have the same thing.

Please help!! Many thanks,
Richard

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! This is a common gotcha, see the linked duplicate for an explanation.

Comment: `[{}]*4` creates shallow copies, change in one `{}` changes the remaining.